# AWS Lambda method using http.request never hits error event, even with 500 response

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

TLDR: How do I log `http` 500 errors in Lambda?

I'm trying to log errors from my internal API method (not accessible to SNS subscription directly), invoked in Lambda, in CloudWatch. Here is my Lambda method in nodejs 6.10:

```
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var post_data = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    var post_options = {
        host: 'myhost.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/path/to/api/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': post_data.length
        }
    };
    var post_request = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
        var body = '';

        res.on('data', function(chunk)  {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
           callback(null, body);//This event happens, even when server returns 500
        });

        res.on('error', function(e) {
            callback(e);//This event never gets called
        });
    });

    post_request.on('error', function(e) {
        callback(e);//This event never gets called either
    });

    post_request.end(post_data);
};
```

My API method is returning a 500. However, my `post_request.on('error')` or `res.on('error')` event is never executing. It always runs the `res.on('end')` instead.

I'd like to report the full error in cloudwatch, but instead it just gives me a generic error message, while saying the lambda method was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quirk with the what node considers an 'error'. As far as the http library is concerned, there was no error. It connected successfully to your api and successfully returned the result the server gave. The error handler will only fire with things like TCP errors or a mangled repsponse. If you want sensible behavior then you'll need to check the status code on the response.

```
var post_request = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
    if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299)
        // handle non-200 https errors;
    }
    // more code
})
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense, confusing that with javascript it looks the same as a jquery ajax method. let me try this.

Comment: confirmed, sorry it took so long, busy day! thanks again!